# @font-face: Firefox requires user to allow download of font file

Tags: firefox, font-face

Running a site on the CargoCollective platform.

Specifying @font-face as follows:

```
@font-face {    font-family: 'Meta';
                src:    url('https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7160824_3237110_68577?directDownload=true') format('embedded-opentype'),
                        url('https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7160824_3237110_68571?directDownload=true') format('truetype'),
                        url('https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7160824_3237110_68573?directDownload=true') format('woff'),
                        url('https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7160824_3237110_68579?directDownload=true#Meta') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.01);
                }
```

Works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Should work in IE since it's got EOT at the top and the URL contains a '?' making IE think the alternates are a query string, though I have no way of testing this as I am on mac.

Problem is that in Firefox (10.0.2, Mac), the font being requested seems to need authorisation to download the font, so it never does download it, and I'm presented with the  default serif, which alters the appearance dramatically.

Styling is declared also in the CSS, as usual, with correct hierarchy structure, for example:

```
body { 
       font-family: Meta, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
      }
```

Not sure why this isn't working, frankly. I've heard it said that Firefox usually downloads the last font in the list, which I have as the SVG as a reading-order 'last resort' filetype, and the font name specified using #Fontname at the end of the URL. Could this be the problem? Can I elect not to specify the SVG Font Name, if this is the case?

I also have this not working in Firefox on another of my websites also hosted on Cargo.

Situation there differs a little, and seems to rule out the obvious issues with this one:

There, the code uses the old 'bulletproof' method:

```
@font-face {    font-family: 'Egyptienne';
                src url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34000443/My%20Site%20Fonts/Egyptienne/Web/Egyptienne/egyptiennef-roman-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
                src: local('☺'),
                url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34000443/My%20Site%20Fonts/Egyptienne/Web/Egyptienne/egyptiennef-roman-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34000443/My%20Site%20Fonts/Egyptienne/Web/Egyptienne/egyptiennef-roman-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34000443/My%20Site%20Fonts/Egyptienne/Web/Egyptienne/egyptiennef-roman-webfont.svg') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.01);
                }
```

But again, the font never loads, and I'm left with ol' Mr. Default.

Differences that I thought may be the issue in the other situation but which seem to be ruled out by this one:

- HTTP vs HTTPS (I initially thought it was an issue with being behind the S of HTTPS)
- SVG Name is never specified, and there's not even a query string to confuse it

[Also, probably irrelevant but before someone asks, the text-shadow property is to minutely improve text rendering in windows.]

Finally, I assume the problem is with Access Control Headers, but how does one append these to font-face code, since there is no .htaccess available to edit?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is? Which URL fails requesting what kind of authorization?

Comment: The font is supposed to download automatically in the background to allow it to render as part of the page. The issue arises because Firefox seems to want the user to 'allow' the download of the font, but there is no dialog to let them, so it ignores it altogether and substitues the default font. Pasting any of the font URLs into the Firefox address bar presents you with the regular file download dialog.

Comment: What exactly gives you the impression that Firefox wants this? What messages or dialogs are you getting?

Comment: That's just it, I'm getting no dialog, but when I use the direct download URLs they prompt to allow the download. If it's something else, please offer your expertise, as I am lost - I am merely assuming it's this.

Comment: prompt how? Using the normal basic auth dialog?

Comment: Yeah, The 'save file/cancel' one.

Comment: Nah, that's not an authorization dialog, that's the download dialog. That's normal when accessing a font file. The problem must be something else

Comment: So this would occur even if it was working properly?

Comment: yup. The dialog comes up when the browser doesn't know how to display a file.

Comment: Ah okay, that's partially good news, then... though I still don't know what the issue is...

Website is oval-uk.com if you want to check

Comment: I don't have a Firebug install handy but have you checked what gets loaded in Firefox? Using FB's "Net" tab?

Comment: Image shows Net tab: [image](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/7559/screenshot20120308at104.png) Appears that FF downloads the otf font first, which it shouldn't, then TTF, then WOFF. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not allow you to load font resources from a different domain. You would have to explicitly allow this via an .htaccess file on the dropbox.com server.

Here's a snippet:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Or even better, since the above code will allow anyone to leach:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|woff|ttf)$">
  SetEnvIf Origin »
    "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain1\.org|domain\.com)$" origin_is=$0
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
</FilesMatch>
```

More information can be found here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems

Comment: This looks definitely like the answer, but how do I make firefox look for the .htaccess on dropbox, located at [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34000443/My%20Site%20Fonts/Meta/.htaccess) ? Not sure what else needs to be in the file either. Sorry, seems I am more novice at this than I had realised.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem. This was bad permission configuration of the application. More specific with de /fonts/ folder. The application was restricting the access to the resources of the /fonts/ folder. So force the browser to download the fonts... sorry about my english.